# Minting of Fantom token with Hardhat fails

Tags: hardhat, fantom, axelar

I've created an IBC token on Fantom using the Axelar portal, which allows mint/burn operations.  Here's the token in question: https://testnet.interchain.axelar.dev/fantom/0xDEdbd54Ffc534a1aEC6D290E7FC5a337218D2708

Using the portal I can mint tokens but when I attempt it programmatically using Hardhat, it doesn't work.  Here's the token I've created: Here's the code I'm employing:

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");
const ABI = require("./utils/interchainTokenABI");

const tokenAddr = "0xDEdbd54Ffc534a1aEC6D290E7FC5a337218D2708"
const destAddr = "0xD5070f2a2C706C086407Ac8F3Bd4F21e3E46Cb99"

var main = async () => {
    var signers = await hre.ethers.getSigners()
    var token = new hre.ethers.Contract(tokenAddr, ABI, signers[0])

    var res = await token.mint(destAddr, 2000)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
}

main().then(() => process.exit())
```

and my `hardhat.config.js`:

```js
 require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });

const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.18",
  networks: {
    fantom: {
      url: "https://rpc.ankr.com/fantom_testnet",
      chainId: 4002,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
};
```

I also have a `.env` file with a single line `PRIVATE_KEY=...` where the ellipsis is the private key I used to create the contract

now, when I run this I get a transaction hash, but I never receive receive the tokens (the tokens should be sent to the account that deployed the contract).  here's the output:

> {"_type":"TransactionResponse","accessList":[],"blockNumber":1,"blockHash":"0xfc8671a9f2d10caaf3753096cf5f9cdae9a020dd95f4439c1c3273c3a0b3a58c","blobVersionedHashes":null,"chainId":"31337","data":"0x40c10f19000000000000000000000000d5070f2a2c706c086407ac8f3bd4f21e3e46cb9900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007d0","from":"0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266","gasLimit":"30000000","gasPrice":"1875000000","hash":"0xb437d1a075f998664445d010241bb8e14f527ca62636a3b5f39e5f46c76799e8","maxFeePerGas":"2750000000","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"1000000000","maxFeePerBlobGas":null,"nonce":0,"signature":{"_type":"signature","networkV":null,"r":"0xf77742adb4d92b1c1d68b0465bceef51ab66e71ec509ad86e893b5a8b99a3289","s":"0x2cd87c119a2b1be0bcd2bce5af149d4758bc7cf1de9f8ea65058ec67b541904e","v":27},"to":"0xDEdbd54Ffc534a1aEC6D290E7FC5a337218D2708","type":2,"value":"0"}

I also tried specifying the token's Manager contract address instead.  that fails too

finally, when I look for the transaction hash in the blockchain explorers (I've looked in both https://testnet.axelarscan.io and https://testnet.ftmscan.com/tx/ as I'm not sure where I should be looking), it's not there.  so I'm guessing the transaction is not getting broadcast

help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Hardhat uses its in-memory Hardhat Network.  Your transactions are therefore being processed locally and are not being sent to the Fantom chain.

If running your script via the Hardhat CLI, use the `network` flag:

```
hardhat run path/to/script --network fantom
```

You can also override the default network in `hardhat.config.js`:

```
module.exports = { defaultNetwork: 'fantom', ... }
```

Comment: that was it! I would upvote your response but I don't have enough reputation to do it :(